# Cannot convert source type 'void' to target type 'ICollection<Character>'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, type-conversion, entity-framework-5

I have a `DataContract` class that I'm trying to convert to another class, `Movie` but for the property `Movie.Characters` I'm getting the error...

> Cannot convert source type '`void`' to target type '`ICollection<Character>`'

How can I create a new `Movie` so the `Character` property is set properly mapped to each `Person` and `Movie`?

```
var movies = dataContract.Movies.Select(m => new Movie {
    Id = m.Id,
    Title = m.Title,
    Characters = m.AbridgedCast.ToList().ForEach(p => new Person { Name = p.Name, 
        RottenTomatoesId = p.Id, 
        Characters = p.Characters.ToList().ForEach(c => new Character { Name = c })})
});
```

**MoviesDataContract.cs**

```
public class MoviesDataContract {
    [DataMember(Name = "total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "movies")]
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    #region Internal Classes

    [DataContract]
    public class Movie {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "abridged_cast")]
        public virtual IEnumerable<Person> AbridgedCast { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Person {
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "characters")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Characters { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion  
}
```

**Movies.cs**

```
public partial class Movie {
    public Movie() {
        this.Characters = new HashSet<Character>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }
}

public partial class Character {
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public partial class Person {
    public Person() {
        this.Characters = new HashSet<Character>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RottenTomatoesId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>.ForEach(...)` doesn't return anything. [See on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx).

You might want to do a projection with `Select(...)` then `ToList()`.

Comment: Shouldn't it return an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: I would have it return an hydrated list, not just a boxed `IQueryable`.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what you mean by hydrated list? I don't know what that term means.

Comment: @bflemi3 `ForEach` is just a helper method that iterates over the collection (like a standard `foreach`) but returns nothing. Change it to use `Select` instead (with a `.ToList` call at the end): `Characters = m.AbridgedCast.Select(p => new Person { Name = p.Name, RottenTomatoesId = p.Id, Characters = p.Characters.Select(c => new Character { Name = c }).ToList() }).ToList()`